# Entity framework table creating c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Database named SalesERPDB and I'm trying to create a new table "TblEmployee", but getting an exception on creating the same.

```
public class SalesERPDB : DbContext
{
    public SalesERPDB() : base("SalesERPDB")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("TblEmployee");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

EmployeeBusinessLayer class (Where i have a method GetEmployees() to get the employee list):

```
public class EmployeeBusinessLayer
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        SalesERPDB salesDal = new SalesERPDB();
        return salesDal.Employees.ToList(); // Getting an exception in this line.
    }
}
```

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to hit the same connection string from a different application.

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SalesERPDB" connectionString="Data Source=CSCINDAI406933\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SalesERPDB;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient"></add>
```

Exception details:

Description: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

**Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.
Stack trace: [InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.]
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +323
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +119
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +362
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +405
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +459
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +190
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +82
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +194
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +427
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CheckDatabaseExists(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, String databaseName) +86
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbDatabaseExists(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Lazy`1 storeItemCollection) +347
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.DatabaseExists(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Lazy`1 storeItemCollection) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9644037
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155**

Fix for this issue would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: update ur question with connection string

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan Updated the question with connectionString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you got the error "instance failure" based on stack trace , that might be the error with your SQL Server instance.  change data source like                                                           `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Yes, The issue was with my Server instance, updated Data Source value to \SQLEXPRESS from \\SQLEXPRESS. It worked.